# Validar longitud de campos en una entidad

Tags: java, base-de-datos, spring-boot, validación, hibernate

Tengo un end-point que actúa directamente con una `entidad`, es decir, tengo el siguiente `controlador`:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Persona> create(@RequestBody Persona person){
    return new ResponseEntity<Persona>(service.create(person), null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

que trabaja sobre la `entidad` Persona (relacionado directamente con mi base de datos).

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Persona {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String name;
```

Lo que quiero hacer, es limitar la longitud del campo 'name' que introduce el usuario que llama a este end-point, sin embargo no quiero modificar la longitud que tiene en `base de datos`.

Por ejemplo, en `base de datos` este campo tiene una longitud de 46 caracteres, pero yo quiero permitir introducir solamente 30.

He estado leyendo otros posts, y en teoría, utilizando la anotación `@Size` (con `max` y `min` value) debería valer, sin embargo, he modificado mi `entidad` dejándola de la siguiente manera, y sigue sin funcionar:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Validated
public class Persona {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column
    @Size(max=30)
    private String name;
```

Si al `controllador` con el método POST le paso un objeto Persona con un 'name' con longitud 40, por ejemplo, no valida nada y lo guarda en base de datos.

¿Hay alguna manera de controlar esto a nivel de entidad? ¿Estoy realizando algo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Spring Boot lo que tiene que hacer es utilizar la anotación `@Valid` en el Objeto de entrada del servicio para que se apliquen las validaciones que tenga el POJO por ejemplo `@Size(max=30) @Min(1) @Max(100)`.

El código seria:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Persona> create(@RequestBody @Valid Persona person){
    return new ResponseEntity<Persona>(service.create(person), null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Lo que debes de tener en cuenta es que el mensaje de validación sera en Ingles, pero si quieres colocar tu propio mensajes debes agregar el parámetro `message` en la anotación de validación por ejemplo:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Validated
public class Persona {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column
    @Size(max=30, message = "El tamaño máximo del campo name es 30")
    private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La anotación @Validated sirve para validar grupos de campos, por ejemplo para validar formularios de varios pasos. Un ejemplo lo puedes encontrar [aquí](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated)

En tu caso puedes usar la anotación @Valid en el controller, a nivel de método, para aplicar las validaciones definidas en la clase Persona.
El método create en el controlador quedaría así:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Persona> create(@RequestBody @Valid Persona person){
    return new ResponseEntity<Persona>(service.create(person), null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tendrias que modificar la siguiente parte del  **PostMapping**
No Olvides utilizar el try y el catch para evitar problemas y excepciones

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Persona> create(@RequestBody Persona person)throws Exception {
    try{
        if (person.getName().length() > 30) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Persona>(service.create(person), null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Si quieres en mensajes seria algo asi :

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody Persona person)throws Exception{
    Map<String, Object> msg = new HashMap<>();
    try{
        if (person.getName().length() > 30) {
            msg.put("no puedes ingresar mas de 30 caracteres");
        }
        else{
            Persona obj = service.create(person);
            msg.put("Guardado Exitoso");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(msg);
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       msg.put("mensaje", "Error la crear una persona" + e.getMessage());
   }       
}
```

Espero Haberte ayudado gracias :D